# Display Blank (ASUS PB278Q) after turning display power off/on until reboot

Tags: display, bluetooth, 15.10, intel-nuc

**Facts:**
I am running Kubuntu 15.10 on Intel NUC D54250wyk (Intel HD Graphic 5000).
My display is ASUS PB278Q connected to NUC on the DP on max resolution (2560x1440).
In System Settings, all Power Management -> Energy Saving Options are off.
I have bluetooth keyboard/mouse (Logitech K330).

**Symptoms**:
After turning off monitor power for long time (night), and turning power on again, monitor displays no signal on DP.  Pressing key on the keyboard does not help. The only way out is to reboot NUC.

**Update:**

1. Wireless keyboard is not a problem.  I replaced it with regular one.
2. It is enough to turn monitor off for 1 minute to have the same problem. Again all Energy Savings options are off.
3. In Intel Visual BIOS I changed: Devices -> Video ->IGD Primary Video Port : Display Port (Default was Auto).  It made no difference.
4. CTRL+ALT Fn (n=1-6) brings ttyn, but when I press CTRL+ALT F7 display shows No Signal on DP

I suspect it must be a video driver issue. I would appreciate any suggestion...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short problem fixed.

**First**:
I installed Kubuntu 15.10 on November 1, '15. I did not apply any updates till yesterday. After running Muon Update Manager, the problem no longer exists. The list of updated packages below (I don't know what fixed it):

```
2015-11-05 00:14:09 upgrade libnm-util2:amd64 1.0.4-0ubuntu5 1.0.4-0ubuntu5.1
2015-11-05 00:14:09 upgrade libnm-glib-vpn1:amd64 1.0.4-0ubuntu5 1.0.4-0ubuntu5.1
2015-11-05 00:14:10 upgrade libnm-glib4:amd64 1.0.4-0ubuntu5 1.0.4-0ubuntu5.1
2015-11-05 00:14:09 upgrade libnm-util2:amd64 1.0.4-0ubuntu5 1.0.4-0ubuntu5.1
2015-11-05 00:14:09 upgrade libnm-glib-vpn1:amd64 1.0.4-0ubuntu5 1.0.4-0ubuntu5.1
2015-11-05 00:14:10 upgrade libnm-glib4:amd64 1.0.4-0ubuntu5 1.0.4-0ubuntu5.1
2015-11-05 00:14:11 upgrade libnm0:amd64 1.0.4-0ubuntu5 1.0.4-0ubuntu5.1
2015-11-05 00:14:11 upgrade libnspr4:amd64 2:4.10.8-2ubuntu1 2:4.10.10-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
2015-11-05 00:14:12 upgrade libnss3-nssdb:all 2:3.19.2-1ubuntu1 2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
2015-11-05 00:14:12 upgrade libnss3:amd64 2:3.19.2-1ubuntu1 2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.15.10.1
2015-11-05 00:14:26 upgrade software-properties-common:all 0.96.13 0.96.13.1
2015-11-05 00:14:27 upgrade software-properties-kde:all 0.96.13 0.96.13.1
2015-11-05 00:14:28 upgrade unzip:amd64 6.0-17ubuntu1 6.0-17ubuntu1.1
2015-11-05 00:14:30 trigproc dbus:amd64 1.10.0-1ubuntu1 
2015-11-05 00:14:30 trigproc ureadahead:amd64 0.100.0-19 
2015-11-05 00:14:31 configure libnm-util2:amd64 1.0.4-0ubuntu5.1 
2015-11-05 00:14:31 configure libnm-glib-vpn1:amd64 1.0.4-0ubuntu5.1 
2015-11-05 00:14:31 configure libnm0:amd64 1.0.4-0ubuntu5.1 
2015-11-05 00:14:31 configure libnspr4:amd64 2:4.10.10-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 
2015-11-05 00:14:32 configure linux-firmware:all 1.149.1 
2015-11-05 00:14:32 configure network-manager:amd64 1.0.4-0ubuntu5.1 
2015-11-05 00:14:33 configure python3-software-properties:all 0.96.13.1 
2015-11-05 00:14:34 configure software-properties-kde:all 0.96.13.1 
2015-11-05 00:14:34 configure libnss3-nssdb:all 2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 
2015-11-05 00:14:34 configure libnss3:amd64 2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.15.10.1 
2015-11-05 00:14:34 trigproc libc-bin:amd64 2.21-0ubuntu4
```

**Second:**
The Intel NUC D54250wyk I have purchased early this year had original BIOS version 0033. If you go through the release notes on Intel site [BIOS Update Release Notes](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/25352/eng/WY_0041_ReleaseNotes.pdf) , you will see that in BIOS version 0038 in April, 2015 Intel, among other things, *Fixed issue where system with Linux Ubuntu cannot resume from sleep*. Updating BIOS on NUC is a breeze - just follow instructions [Intel BIOS Readme notes](https://downloadmirror.intel.com/25352/eng/NUC-BIOS-Update-Readme.pdf) and the Intel Visual BIOS 0041 is much, much simpler than earlier versions.

**Lesson learned:**

1. You are on your own when you are on a 'cutting edge' of Kubuntu releases and if you are using 'fancy' hardware.
2. Keep updating newly released software

**PS**. To my fellow AskUbuntu community members: please answer your own questions if you found the solution, even when nobody seems to be interested in your problem.